# Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class <Class> could not be converted to string in ...\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr.php line 568

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i, am creating a marketplace, with tags and sort order, tags work properly, but when I had the sorting code, it says :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class \Entity\Category could not beconverted to
string in \vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr.php line 568
```

I search on google, nobody had the same problem?
My code :

```
public function tagAction($tag, $sort) {

    $rep = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('RSHubMarketplaceBundle:Modification');
    $tags = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('RSHubMarketplaceBundle:Category')
    ->findAll();
    if($tag == -1){
            $stags = $tags;

    } else {
        $tag = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('RSHubMarketplaceBundle:Category')
    ->find($tag);
        $stags = array($tag); 
    }
    switch ($sort) {
    case 'popularity':
        $mods = $rep->getByPopularity( array($tag));
        break;
    case 'downloads':
        $mods = $rep->getByDownloads( array($tag));
        break;
    case 'newest':
        $mods = $rep->getByNewest(array($tag));
        break;
    case 'name':
        $mods = $rep->getByName( array($tag));
        break;

    }
    return $this->render('RSHubMarketplaceBundle:Marketplace:index.html.twig',
                    array('categories' => $tags, 'mods' =>$mods,
                            'tag' => $tag));
}
```

And the method where i encounter issues :

```
public function getWithCategoriesOrdered(array $nom_categories, $orderCol, $order) {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

    $qb->join('a.categories', 'c')
            ->where($qb->expr() // HERE
                    ->in('c.name', $nom_categories));
    $qb->add('orderBy', 'a.'.$orderCol.' '.$order);

    return $qb->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two ways

a) add __toString() method in you Category Entity that returns its name

b) supposing that $nom_categories is a category, just need to pass $nom_categories->getName() in your query expression

in this kind of errors(with external libraries) you need to debug and carefully check the stacktrace